# Space on top of content in Firefox

Tags: css, xhtml

If you visit this page in Firefox 3.6:

http://unirazz.com/images/ww/home.html

There is a space of around 10px above the content.

What's causing this extra space on top?

Comment: For explanation please check the screen shot
http://unirazz.com/images/ww/home.jpg

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason, especially since that link is 404 and no longer demonstrates the problem: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with it and I was able to eliminate a bit of the space by turning off the rule `margin: 10px 0;` for the "footer" class... of all things. (I am deeply confused by this.)

Comment: Yes u r right, i removed the margin and converted to padding, now its fine. Whats the cause of this???

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with this line:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

inside the **div.header**

the **clear:both** in it's css makes the problem.

delete this tag and instead use the [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

like this:

add a class clearfix to div.header:

```
<div class="header clearfix">
```

then add these lines to your css:

```
.clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

please note the second line carefully:
**content: "";**

Answer (score 0):

Firefox gets confused with margin on the page. You can fix it using:

```
div.content {
   padding: 1px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could also be an overlapped div that's pushing the content div down. In my situation constraining the upper div to a specific height resolved it.